# Cannot define 'through' relationship on two models which share a base class in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've got a 'set' model, which has a many to many relationship to the 'Item' model. The issue is that 'set' is a subclass of Item (everything is an Item on the project).

It works fine, until I try to create a 'through' relationship to an intermediary model called 'order', which I'm defining so I can order the 'Items' inside the 'Set'.

When I try to define the relationship, I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
curate.Set.items_: (fields.E001) Field names must not end with an underscore.
curate.order.set: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'order.set' clashes with reverse accessor for 'order.item'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'order.set' or 'order.item'.
```

I've tried adding a related_name to Order.set, and also Order.item, but it doesn't seem to work. I can get migrations to be happy, but then when I try to migrate I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: Cannot alter field curate.Set.items into curate.Set.items - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model, AdminVideoMixin):

    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=5000, default='')
   ...

class Video(Item):
    video_embed = EmbedVideoField(max_length=500)
    ...

class Article(Item):
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    ...

class Podcast(Item):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True,)
    ...

class Episode(Item):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True,blank=True,)
    ...

class Set(Item):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='setItems', max_length=5000, through='Order')
    front_page = models.BooleanField(max_length=300, blank=False, default=False, null=False)

class order(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=0)
```

Comment: don't use python keywords as class or variable name. [read](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list)

Comment: Set? Is that going to be a big problem? I'll update that.

Comment: Not only `Set` model, but `set` field of `order` model. And it's a convetion to name your classes with capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a `ManyToMany` field to use a `through` relationship once it has been created. This is because the through table will now contain extra fields that cannot be populated by the standard `ManyToMany` relationship (this is the same reason why you can't use `add`, `clear`, `remove`, `delete` when using a through table). You will need to create a new `ManyToMany` field on `Set` that uses the through relationship and then populate it with the data from `Set.items` before removing `Set.items`.

[Docs on through tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

If you need to have the new field called `items` you can do the following:

- Change `items` to `items_old` in the `Set` model, you will need to change the related_name as well if you would like that to be the same (make and run the migration)
- Add the new `items` field with the through relationship (make and run the migration)
- Populate the new `items` field with the data from `items_old`

```
set_items = Set.objects.filter(items__isnull=False)
Order.objects.bulk_create([
    Order(item=item, set=s)
    for s in set_items
    for item in s.items.all()
])
```

- Remove `items_old` from `Set`

*NB - Like katoozi mentioned in his comment, you probably shouldn't have fields named set*